# "Acess violation" when using a scripted constant

Tags: inno-setup

I need to implement a scripted constant to retrieve a drive of user-selected path.

I tried the code bellow, but I'm getting:

> Acess violation ate adress 0043D8E0.Read of address 01CDE694

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    Page := CreateInputDirPage(
              wpSelectDir,'Select local', 'Where will be stored?', '', False, 'New Folder');

    Page.Add('Local Dserver (APP)');
    Page.Add('Local Images (Storage)');

    Page.Values[0] := ('F:\TEST1');
    Page.Values[1] := ('G:\TEST2');
end;

function ExtractFileDrive(const FileName: string): String;
begin
    Result := ExtractFileDrive(Page.Values[0]);
end;

[Run]
Filename: {code:ExtractFileDrive|0}\postgresql-9.4.5-1-windows-x64.exe
```

Comment: What error occurs during installation? - The code looks good - Except that it is not complete - And may need some explanation. Like why do you expect the `postgresql-9.4.5-1-windows-x64.exe` is a root folder of some drive?

Comment: Martin, ocours the error "Acess violation ate adress 0043D8E0.Read of address 01CDE694".

I need to know the drive because my app can be installed in any drive. So the user will put in the same root this installer and the installer of Postgres.

Comment: So you require the use to put the installer there manually? Why? Why don't you embed it to the installer? - Why do you ask the user for a path, if you care about a drive only? - Anyway, show us, how you use the code with the `CreateInputDirPage` - We need [mcve].

Comment: I have two default paths, drive F and G. My application runs normally in F: \ TESTE1.
But depending on necessity I can install in other path, for example, F: \ TESTEAlternative or n: \ TESTE1
That's why I need to know the drive to run Postgres installer. The user must put Postgres installer in the same drive, to easier the installation.
I do not know if I done by understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ExtractFileDrive` scripted constant shadows the [`ExtractFileDrive` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfiledrive). So you recursively call your `ExtractFileDrive` function from itself ad infinitum, until the stack overflows.

Just rename your function to anything else.

*And once doing that, rename its argument, as the `FileName` is confusing. And also remove the scripted constant parameter in its use, as you actually do not use it.*

```pascal
[Code]

function GetFileDrive(Param: string): String;
begin
  Result := ExtractFileDrive(Page.Values[0]);
end;

[Run]
Filename: {code:GetFileDrive}\postgresql-9.4.5-1-windows-x64.exe
```